# Tips on how to speed up ZSH shell start up time

Tags: terminal, shell, zsh, wsl2, oh-my-zsh

can someone help me understand why my Zsh start up is so slow. My Zsh takes up to six 6 seconds to start up so I added `zmodload zsh/zprof` and `zprof` to my .zshrc to see what takes the most time. The output is below:

```
-- console output produced during zsh initialization follows --

num  calls                time                       self            name
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1)    1        7432.11  7432.11   97.31%   4124.58  4124.58   54.01%  nvm_auto
 2)    2        3307.53  1653.77   43.31%   1874.60   937.30   24.55%  nvm
 3)    1        1211.54  1211.54   15.86%   1061.18  1061.18   13.89%  nvm_ensure_version_installed
 4)    1         198.66   198.66    2.60%    195.42   195.42    2.56%  nvm_die_on_prefix
 5)    1         150.37   150.37    1.97%    150.37   150.37    1.97%  nvm_is_version_installed
 6)    1         119.08   119.08    1.56%    119.08   119.08    1.56%  compdump
 7)  802          28.39     0.04    0.37%     28.39     0.04    0.37%  compdef
 8)    2         179.63    89.82    2.35%     26.56    13.28    0.35%  compinit
 9)    1          22.73    22.73    0.30%     22.73    22.73    0.30%  nvm_has
10)    7          16.51     2.36    0.22%     13.53     1.93    0.18%  (anon)
11)    4           6.10     1.53    0.08%      6.10     1.53    0.08%  compaudit
12)    1           5.52     5.52    0.07%      5.52     5.52    0.07%  zrecompile
13)    4           3.24     0.81    0.04%      3.24     0.81    0.04%  nvm_npmrc_bad_news_bears
14)    1           1.42     1.42    0.02%      1.42     1.42    0.02%  _p9k_init_ssh
15)    1           1.50     1.50    0.02%      1.02     1.02    0.01%  _p9k_preinit
16)    1           0.94     0.94    0.01%      0.94     0.94    0.01%  regexp-replace
17)    2           0.66     0.33    0.01%      0.66     0.33    0.01%  is_plugin
18)    1           0.50     0.50    0.01%      0.50     0.50    0.01%  colors
19)    4           0.35     0.09    0.00%      0.35     0.09    0.00%  add-zsh-hook
20)    3           0.32     0.11    0.00%      0.32     0.11    0.00%  is-at-least
21)    1           0.48     0.48    0.01%      0.22     0.22    0.00%  gitstatus_start_p9k_
22)    1           0.18     0.18    0.00%      0.09     0.09    0.00%  complete
23)    1           0.24     0.24    0.00%      0.07     0.07    0.00%  prompt_powerlevel9k_setup
24)    1           0.07     0.07    0.00%      0.07     0.07    0.00%  p10k
25)    1           0.15     0.15    0.00%      0.06     0.06    0.00%  prompt_powerlevel9k_teardown
26)    2           0.04     0.02    0.00%      0.04     0.02    0.00%  bashcompinit
27)    1        7432.14  7432.14   97.31%      0.03     0.03    0.00%  nvm_process_parameters
28)    2           0.03     0.01    0.00%      0.03     0.01    0.00%  is_theme
29)    1           0.03     0.03    0.00%      0.03     0.03    0.00%  detect-clipboard
30)    2           0.02     0.01    0.00%      0.02     0.01    0.00%  env_default
31)    2           0.17     0.08    0.00%      0.02     0.01    0.00%  _p9k_setup
32)    1           0.01     0.01    0.00%      0.01     0.01    0.00%  nvm_is_zsh
33)    2           0.01     0.01    0.00%      0.01     0.01    0.00%  _p9k_restore_special_params
34)    1           0.01     0.01    0.00%      0.01     0.01    0.00%  _p9k_init_toolbox

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From my understanding, nvm_auto is taking up 97% of start up but I'm not sure what I can do to make it faster? If anyone has any good tips or has experienced this before can I get some help?

Comment: Not an answer, but I had a very similar situation 4 years ago with my Zsh startup.  `nvm` was definitely one of the problems, but also not the only one.  I had a pretty complex startup, and I spent days troubleshooting it to try to get startup times back into the 1-2 range.  I ended up switching to Fish, which provided most of my Zsh customizations (and more) with no additional config.  I also switched from `nvm` to `n` around that time, since I liked the way that I could configure `n` via Fish's universal variables and not have to worry about a complicated startup. I was on WSL1 at the time.

Comment: I know it's not useful (or even constructive) to say, "Don't use Zsh."  It's just that it was the route I ended up going ;-).  I know that plenty of people use Zsh and `nvm` without issue, so hopefully you'll get a solution to your actual problem!